# In the code below, I am using a template string. FCC will not pass me because it does not recognize it

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, string-interpolation, template-strings

Here is this challenge [@freeCodeCamp](https://learn.freecodecamp.org/javascript-algorithms-and-data-structures/es6/create-strings-using-template-literals)

Here is my code:

```
const result = {
success: ["max-length", "no-amd", "prefer-arrow-functions"],
failure: ["no-var", "var-on-top", "linebreak"],
skipped: ["id-blacklist", "no-dup-keys"]
};
function makeList(arr) {
  "use strict";

  // change code below this line
  const resultDisplayArray = [`<li class="text-warning">${arr[0]}</li>`, `<li class="text-warning">${arr[1]}</li>`, `<li class="text-warning">${arr[2]}</li>`];
  // change code above this line

  return resultDisplayArray;
}
/**
 * makeList(result.failure) should return:
 * [ <li class="text-warning">no-var</li>,
 *   <li class="text-warning">var-on-top</li>, 
 *   <li class="text-warning">linebreak</li> ]
 **/
const resultDisplayArray = makeList(result.failure);
```

I do not know if the error is a result of me missing something or an error on FCC's part? Even in the console when I am using the Template Literal I am able to call resultDisplayArray and it is the expected value.

Comment: You'll need to explain more. This doesn't make much sense. Can you explain the objective of the project better?

Comment: There seems to be an error with the platform, in that case.

Comment: Try this instead: `const makeList = arr => arr.map(item => \`<li class="text-warning">${item}</li>\`);`